# Error when installing Termite Style

Tags: linux, terminal

I followed this [github tutorial](https://github.com/adi1090x/termite-style), to install termite-style.

However, when I run `./install`, I get the following error:

```
[!] ERROR: Could not find 'termite', is it installed?
```

Screenshot:

> [image: Termite Style install error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you installed `termite` on your system? That github tutorial is intended for `termite` obviously.

Comment: That are only the Styles for termite. Do you have termite itself installed before?

Comment: You need to [add information](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/638263/edit) to your question. What steps have you performed to find the cause of this error? The error message seems to be obvious to me; `termite` is not found on your computer. Is it installed? If yes, can you run it? When did the error message occur - during the installation of `termite-style`, and at which step? If it's during the `install` script, have to tried to find out which command in the script leads to the error? Or did the message occur later, in which case tell us which action of yours generated the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
which termite
```

If you do not get any output from this command `termite` is not installed the link you supplied is for installing an addon for the termite terminal not to install  the terminal it's self.  Make sure you have termite installed first then retry the directions on github.

Comment: [Don’t use `which`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/86440).

Comment: Why not? This comment provides no context and does not expand on the issue at hand.  Please provide an explanation on why not to use `which`, I am honestly interested.

Comment: It’s a link, click on it and all your questions should be answered.